# How to show a X mark in checkbox when ng-disabled value true in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, checkbox

I need to show an X mark in red color for checkboxes, if `ng-disabled`  condition satisfies `true`. How to achieve this? I'm new to Angular.js anyone help me.

This is I have tried so far:

```
if (module.Name === 'val1' || module.Name === 'val2') {
  return true; // Here I'm validate ng-disables true or false
}
```

Comment: You mean when the checkbox is disabled you want to put an x mark in it ?

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: So all disabled checkboxes will be checked?

Comment: Yes...I need to show cross mark instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/20IqOmvq3oN0ZS40hlx7?p=preview)**.

Here's the data structure:

```
 $scope.checkboxes = [{
   name: 'val1',
 }, {
   name: 'val2',
 }, {
   name: 'val3'
 }];
```

Here's the template:

```
  <div ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isDisabled(checkbox)" ng-disabled="isDisabled(checkbox)"/>
    {{checkbox.name}}
  </div>
```

Then the function for checking if the checkbox is disabled:

```
 $scope.isDisabled = function(module) {
  if (module.name === 'val1' || module.name === 'val2') {
    return true; // Here I'm validate ng-disables true or false
  }
 }
```

Comment: Here it's a CSS question, not concern angular

Comment: I have added css tag.Could you get my problem and give me a solution anyhow?

Comment: I think you don't need any help for customizing an input checkbox, it has already been solved a lot of times on Stackoverflow